# Filtrar por año un dataframe y graficar con gráfica lineal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Espero que estén bien. Necesito hacer un filtro en un dataframe para conocer el número de desmovilizados en un rango de años. Logré filtrarlo, creo que bien, pero al momento de graficarlo en forma lineal no sé como organizarlo o estoy pasando un valor inadecuado. Me gustaría saber como graficarlo o si estoy filtrando mal cual sería la manera adecuada. MUCHAS GRACIAS

En caso dado que se necesite los datos con el cual estoy trabajando es un csv que convierto en dataframe [Aqui esta el archivo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3LmXBidBq9GDmDS-SMkBBOhJTuvZqs_/view)

Mi el código que tengo este:

```
filtro_año = (prueba['AnioDesmovilizacion']>=2004) & (prueba['AnioDesmovilizacion']<=2005)#Aqui filtro por los años de prueba que puse

filtrox = prueba[filtro_año]#Aqui pase la variable de la condicion para poder señalarlos en el dataframe
filtroy = filtrox['AnioDesmovilizacion'].value_counts()#Aqui los cuento para saber cuanto hay por año que cumple la condición inicial

pruebax = filtroy.keys()

plt.plot(filtrox, pruebax)#aqui realmente no se que valores variables poner para graficar bien
plt.show()
```

Con este código me arroja un error el cual es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ejemplo sobre como debo graficarlo es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que años quieres tomar en cuenta?? por que aquí estas tomando los años 2004 y 2005 pero en el gráfico muestras los años desde 2005 hasta 2010

Comment: El grafico es de ejemplo y los datos 2004/05 también, para saber si el filtro funcionaba bien, creo que si funciona bien, son de ejemplo esos datos.

Comment: entonces supongo que puedes hacer `plt.plot(filtroy)`

Comment: Lo realice así y no me aparece bien, me grafica desordenadamente.

Comment: Ya agregue una respuesta a mi misma pregunta con los cambios y como quedo la grafica, me gustaría que me corrigiera lo malo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que los datos no están ordenados, por lo que primero tenemos que ordenarlos de acuerdo al año para que se grafiquen en orden, para esto haremos uso de la función `sorted` y de su parámetro `key` que indica en base a que ordenaremos, en este caso será el año.

```py
filtro_año = (df['AnioDesmovilizacion']>=2005) & (df['AnioDesmovilizacion']<=2010)

filtrox = df[filtro_año]
filtroy = filtrox['AnioDesmovilizacion'].value_counts()

#comprensión de diccionario
pruebax = dict(sorted(filtroy.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

y = list(pruebax.values())
x = list(pruebax.keys())

plt.plot(x,y)
# plt.gcf().set_size_inches(9, 7) #hacemos más grande el gráfico
plt.show()
```

utilizamos el método `items` porque nos devuelve una lista de tuplas, así `[(key1,val1), (key2,val2), ...]` esto nos sirve para poder decirle al parámetro `key` que ordene en base a alguna posición o elemento de la tupla, en este caso decimos que lo haga en base al primer elemento (`[0]`) que sería donde se ubica el año en todas las tuplas. La función `sorted` nos retorna una lista de tuplas y este resultado lo convertimos a un diccionario empleando la clase `dict`.

Luego solo nos resta separar los valores `x` y `y` por lo que usamos los método `keys()` para obtener las claves y el método `values()` para obtener los valores y eso lo guardamos en sus variables respectivas.

Luego solo debemos de graficarlo.

Lo ideal para ti sería graficar una serie de tiempo y hacer uso de `plt.plot_date()` y obviamente tendrás que usar el módulo `datetime`. Esto te lo dejo para que investigues y te diviertas un poco más, igual recuerda que cualquier duda que tengas me la puedes hacer en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendi muy bien. Buscare lo que me recomendaste

Comment: items no devuelve una lista de tuplas. Devuelve (según la documentación) una [vista](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Comment: @DanteS. Lo digo así para que sea fácil de entender (y aveces me da pereza explicar). Lo que enrealidad retorna es un conjunto de elementos de forma `(key,value)`. Pero bueno, igual gracias por detallarlo

Comment: Entiendo! De nada!

Answer (score 0):

Lo modifique como me recomendaron en comentarios pero ahora con un rango mas grande de datos y el resultado fue este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código quedo así:

```
filtro_año = (df['AnioDesmovilizacion']>=2005) & (df['AnioDesmovilizacion']<=2010)

filtrox = df[filtro_año]
filtroy = filtrox['AnioDesmovilizacion'].value_counts()
pruebax = filtroy.keys()

plt.plot(filtroy)
plt.show()
```

Realmente no se como organizarlo para que se vea bien visualmente.

Comment: En un momento publico una respuesta. Por aquí es hora de cenar